# Fixed Sidebar Position and Responsive

Tags: css, media-queries

i want to learn media queries and a little bit more in CSS. As of now i want a fixed sidebar that doesn't scroll down with the content.

Also, I've been reading about Media Queries earlier.. Just couldn't understand them yet.. Maybe a sample will give me hints...

Here's my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>This is a excerpt or a content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To make it short, I'm just trying to imitate this [site](http://qiip.me/edlea/blogger).. just to test my skills. It's looks simple...

As you can see, if you resize the browser window the menu changed,, Is that some kind of jQuery effect? If yes, where can i find a tutorial of that..

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uPpJr/ .. added position fixed to sidebar, now in responsive one just remove the position fixed in media query

Comment: I've just looked at the source code for the example site.  The fixed bar to the right is in an html5 element, aside (it can just be a div).  The CSS for this has a fixed position and a margin left larger than the column on the left that contains the posts.  Set your sidebar div with position fixed.

Comment: a sidebar with a margin-left of more than 700px?

Comment: @Vikas, the sidebar went out of the div. becuase of the right: 0; ?

Answer (score 1):

Media queries: 
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

For the scroll bar your kinda said it yourself.. make it postion:fixed; left: with-of-the-wrapper;
and take the sidebar out of the wrapper div.

Gr.
Kevin

Comment: Oh so the sidebar is outside the wrapper div??  and give the sidebar class a position:fixed ?? Hmm. what about the examples above.. Are those valid too?

Comment: Yes, but they gave you code to use were I only gave you stuff to read and learn from.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d6LYd/3/ changed with for testing purpose. if width aint atleast 600 its floating on top (assuming it would be a menu) else fixed on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the sidebar div when the screen width gets below a particular size like so:

```
@media all and (max-width: 720px) {
  #sidebar {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Or you could float it left which will display at the bottom of the page:

```
@media all and (max-width: 720px) {
      #sidebar {
        float:left;
      }
   }
```

You may need to tweak the CSS a bit as well as the max width to what you personally want the media queries to run at.

Edit - Menu Resize on Mobile

Easiest solution would be to use a Grid Framework.

The two main ones being:

- [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

If you go to their sites and resize the window you will see the menu changing depending on screen size.  Investigate the code and see how they do it and this will help you understand it.  Obviously read all the tutorials too.

Here is also a tutorial that goes through implementing it from scratch http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/a-simple-responsive-mobile-first-navigation/

Comment: Yeah i think i already know about the positions of the div when it meets a certain device width... I guess my question now is the Clickable menu that changes when your viewing it in a small screen.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask regarding the menu resize - try to keep it all in context.  Update your original question to ask about the menu too.

Comment: It's in the question: :) Anyway, thanks for the responsive links. How about the fixed sidebar?

Comment: As mentioned already mentioned you need to make the sidebar div with position of fixed.  In the site example you supplied have a look in the source code and the CSS.  This should help you out.  If my answer helps please mark as answer.

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag could you mark as answer if it has answered your question please?